# How can export to PDF a visualization that is larger than a regular page?

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

[Issue mentioned on Export PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0lXI.png) I have a Page in Spotfire which sometime has a size larger than a regular page, when I export it using IronPython it is exported but the visualization gets cut and is added in a single page, how can extend the export to several pages(I can modify the page size but I would rather to keep it in A4 page size in Portrait Orientation )

I have review the Spotfire API https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/sfire_dev/area/doc/api/TIB_sfire-analyst_api/html/T_Spotfire_Dxp_Application_Export_PdfExportSettings.htm?_ga=2.144772595.67263854.1559743187-1213380950.1541709588

but even if I change the "Scope" or "UseEntirePage" properties I get this behaviour

```
pdfexpsettings = PdfExportSettings()
pdfexpsettings.UseEntirePage = True
pdfexpsettings.IncludePageFooter=True
pdfexpsettings.Scope = ExportScope.ActiveVisualization
pdfexpsettings.IncludeNonVisibleContent = True       
if Document.Properties["Orientation"] == 0:
    pdfexpsettings.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Portrait
else:
    pdfexpsettings.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape
pdfexpsettings.IncludeFilterSettings = False
pdfexpsettings.IncludePageTitles = False
pdfexpsettings.IncludeVisualizationTitles = True
pdfexpsettings.IncludeVisualizationDescriptions = False
size = Document.Properties["Size"]
if size == 0:
    pdfexpsettings.PaperSize = PaperSize.A4
elif size ==1:
    pdfexpsettings.PaperSize = PaperSize.Letter
elif size ==2:
    pdfexpsettings.PaperSize = PaperSize.A0
elif size ==3:
    pdfexpsettings.PaperSize = PaperSize.A1
elif size ==4:
    pdfexpsettings.PaperSize = PaperSize.A2
elif size ==5:
    pdfexpsettings.PaperSize = PaperSize.A3
elif size ==6:
    pdfexpsettings.PaperSize = PaperSize.A5
elif size ==7:
    pdfexpsettings.PaperSize = PaperSize.Legal
if Document.Properties["Orientation"] == 0:
    pdfexpsettings.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Portrait
else:
    pdfexpsettings.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape
```

Comment: If you add `pdfexpsettings.IncludeNonVisibleContent=True` all the rows in the visualisation will get appended to the export.

Comment: @Monte_fisto I did added that property with the property **pdfexpsettings.Scope = ExportScope.ActiveVisualization** and it still same issue